# Static bounds checks on Haskell arrays

Tags: arrays, haskell

Is there any way to get static checks on Haskell arrays? Let's take this code:

```
import Data.Array
let a = listArray (0, 10) [-3.969683028665376e+01, 2.209460984245205e+02, -2.759285104469687e+02, 1.383577518672690e+02, -3.066479806614716e+01, 2.506628277459239e+00]
```

`(0, 10)` should really be `(0, 5)`, but the compiler accepts the code. The error is only detected at runtime, despite the fact that it could be detected at compile-time.

Comment: Perhaps it could be detected *in this case* - **if** the compiler does a lot of inlining and constant-folding to reach an unconditional `error` (or whatever) call. In most nontrivial programs, it can't be detected, at least not with reasonable effort. And then there's this pesky halting problem...

Comment: Use [Habit](http://hasp.cs.pdx.edu/habit-report-Nov2010.pdf) (PDF) Ix types to get a static guarantee of bounds. Bonus points if you port this work to Haskell.

Comment: There is a way, but it's much too inconvenient to be practical. For more on this, try searching the web for "type-level numbers haskell".

Comment: With boxed arrays, there's no reason for the compiler to reject this code. Undefined array elements are perfectly legitimate. It could perhaps issue a warning (but there are probably too few cases which are detectable with reasonable effort to bother).

Comment: @delnan Why? Detecting this problem (you're declaring a 10-element array but only providing values for 6 elements) it's as hard as detecting an error in this C++ code: `boost::array<double,10> = {0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6};`, which any C++ compiler will do. Thus, there is no fundamental reason why it can't be done. There's no halting problem here -- it's all on the same line of code.

Comment: @quant_dev: I never said the halting problem ruins the day in this example. However, the compiler doesn't (necessarily, let's discount rewrite rules etc.) have intrinsic knowledge about `Data.Array` built in, so it would have to inline and constant-fold a lot to see that this expression reduces to an unconditional `error` (or whatever) call. And in many real-world cases, doing so is impossible e.g. because the values come from a file. That's why I wouldn't bother trying to find such errors if I was a GHC guy. If you want the compiler to check it, encode it in types (and have fun going insane).

Comment: I think it's worth doing it for arrays. They are an important object in programming. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This cannot be detected at compile-time, because there's nothing in the list's type that saves its size, so the `listArray` function cannot possibly perform such checks. Also, if the data came from an external file (for example), it would be very difficult to get the static size checking to work.

You need a dependent type system such as the one you find in [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php) for things like this to be possible.

Comment: What is created is not a list, but an array (Data.Array).

Comment: Yes, but you are using a list to create the array. You do `listArray (start, end) someList`.

Comment: But in this piece of code, `someList` is presented explicitly to the compiler, so it could do the check easily. But I think I understand it now: Data.Array is not a native Haskell type.

Comment: Yes, the check is `length someList == end - start` (not really, but almost). You can do this at runtime because the length of the list can be computed then. If you have `do { data <- read <$> readFile "data.list"; let array = listArray (0, 10) data }`, the length cannot be checked during compile time, and Haskell will not "special-case" the situation when you happen to input the list literally (Without Template Haskell). You can of course do `listArray (0, length list - 1) list`  if you want the array to adjust its size to the list.

Comment: OK, so what I want *could* be done in principle, it's just that it's not done by Haskell.